# Display server info to user logging in

Tags: windows, group-policy, windows-server-2012-r2, login-script

Previous to virtualizing our servers and using domain logins we had a practice of creating a wallpaper with the server name and services running on the server so if any technician logged in they wouldn't confuse what machine they were remoted into.

Now that we have 5x the number of servers and each technician using their own domain credentials, is there any way of obviously identifying the server they are remoting into similar to our previous practice?

My first thought was to create a GPO to set the wallpaper for all users, but I would have to create a separate GPO for each server, not to mention creating all of those wallpapers (that idea is out)

Maybe a login script of some sort could notify the user about the machines identity?

creative options are welcomed!

Comment: [bginfo](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bginfo.aspx)

Comment: If you grant RDP access to people who can't be trusted to know which sever they're accessing... well, that's your problem, right there. bginfo, different backgrounds or shell colors, and so on are a convenience, not something to rely on.  This problem is best solved by removing access from people who can't handle it.

Comment: I dont need a shift in conversation @HopelessN00b. Suffice to say that all of my sys admins are trustworthy.

Comment: @jscott I successfully got bginfo up & running with this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-HoO10Ke_6g), however I am stuck with the launch of bginfo.exe being halted by "Open File - Security Warning" is there a way around this?

Comment: @Brian right click bginfo.exe, choose 'properties', check 'unblock', click 'ok'. This removes the NTFS alternate data stream that says the file came from the internet.

Comment: @jscott I used sysinternals streams.exe to remove the flags because I did  not see an unblock option in properties. But it appears that my GPO had already copied BGinfo.exe locally to all the servers before I made this change with streams.exe. I hope it updates the file since it has a created date change.